# How to return a list of strings in Java?

Tags: java, apex

I want to return a list of strings when I call the method `generateArrayList(2);`
It reminds me `"Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void generateArrayList(Integer) from the type anon"`
Anyone help me, please! here is my class:

```
public class StringArrayTest {      
    public static List<String> generateArrayList(integer n){
        List<String> stringArray = new List<String>();
        for (integer i=0;i<n;i++){
            String str= 'Test'+String.valueOf(i);
            stringArray.add(str);
        }
        return stringArray;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you have more success with your method after you fixed all those compiler errors in there?

Comment: From where you are calling method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have few compile time errors which needs to be corrected before it can work correctly.

1. `integer`: It will either be an `int` or an `Integer`. Use `ArrayList`
2. `new List<String>`: It's an interface. You can't instantiate an interface.
3. `'Test'`: Single quotes is used for Character literal, for Strings use double quotes.
4. Also, there's no need of `string.valueOf(i)`.

Below, I have corrected all these errors. It should work now.

```
public static List<String> generateArrayList(int n){
    List<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        String str= "Test" + i;
        stringArray.add(str);
    }
    return stringArray;
}
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the beginning it's hard sometimes.

```java
public static List<String> generateList(Integer n) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String str = "Test" + String.valueOf(i);
        strings.add(str);
    }
    return strings;
}
```

Comment: What ide are you working with? Eclipse or Intellij would highlight errors like those that were present here.

Comment: Salesforce Developer Console.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above is almost correct.  you just need to put "SPACE" after "Test" here it is:

```
public static List<String> generateStringArray(Integer n){       
    List <String> strings = new List<String>();      
        for (Integer i = 0; i < n; i++){
            String str = 'Test ' + String.valueOf(i);
            strings.add(str);
        }
    return strings;
}}
```

also you can write it simplier:

```
public static List<String> generateStringArray(Integer n){       
    List <String> strings = new List<String>();      
        for (Integer i = 0; i < n; i++){
            strings.add('Test ' + i);               
        }
    return strings;
}}
```